# Preprocessor for HTML snippets to JS strings

Tags: javascript

In my project I have a number of snippets of HTML within Javascript strings. These need to be formatted as valid JS - no newlines for example. In this single line format it can be tiring to edit the HTML (also there's no syntax highlighting in my editor).

I had the idea of keeping these snippets as external files and then loading them in at run time but this adds a lot of network calls. The ideal solution would be some kind of preprocessor which could take a number of HTML snippet files and output a JS file with all the HTML parsed into valid JS strings, with filenames as variable names perhaps.

Does anything like this exist? Example:
Input:

snippet_a.html

```
<div>
    My HTML here including whitespace...
</div>
```

snippet_b.html

```
<div>
    More HTML here ...
</div>
```

Output as strings.js file:

```
snippet_a = '<div>My HTML here, whitespace as \n ...</div>';  
snippet_b = '<div>More HTML here ...</div>';
```

Even cooler if it can put the string where it's meant to be in a certain file via a token. I am thinking of workflow solutions along the lines of a CSS preprocessor, JS compiler, Textmate bundle similar to 'Persistant Include', ANT script...

Templating is the usual way to go, But this ties the JS to a particular HTML file where the template was dumped.

IMO something like Textmate persistant include function would be great - this works like a comment you can stick in your HTML file at the place to pull in another file's contents when you hit an 'update' shortcut. Doesn't work for JS or preprocess the contents though.

Comment: Yes! Use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)!

Comment: What language/platform are you using on the server side?

Comment: @chiefGui I just looked at require js site, but couldn't see an example for doing something similar?

Comment: @thg435 It doesn't have to be serverside - just something I can run and grab the output of. I was imagining something like a CSS compiler or a TextMate bundle.

Comment: Post sample of what you have on input and what do you want to get on output.

Comment: You can get the content AND the tags using [`DOMElement .outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)
http://jsfiddle.net/puZuE/

Comment: It's very easy to write such preprocessor by yourself. You need just: 1) read file `snippet_a.html` to string; 2) escape quotes or double quotes; 3) wrap data with quotes or double quotes depending of what you choose in step 2); 4) prepend `var snippet_a = ` (file name without extension) and append trailing newline; 5) write string to output js file. Repeat until all input files processed. I think it's possible with most of programming languages you probably know. Side note: `\n` will be ignored if you'll assign this snippet as `innerHTML` of elem, maybe you'll want to replace it with `<br/>`

Comment: However, I still not sure it's necessary. I always just do hidden div on page and put snippets in it, then when I need snippet data, I just use `$("#snippet_a").html()`.

Comment: @Tommi, Ive updated Q, don't want to tie my .js class files to a particular HTML file where templates may be dumped. And yes there may be some whitespace considerations. Haha, 'write it yourself' could be the solution in the end, just checking first..

Comment: I got your point. I don't believe there is any tool which performs so specialized action, but maybe someone knows more. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Take a look at this article by John Resig *Javascript Micro-Templating* http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Long answer:

There are several ways to overcome the "long line problem", one of the easiest is just to cut the lines by concatenating strings.

```
var snippet = "<h1>A Long html snippet</h1> "+
              "<p>This is a long html snippet that I don't want to be forced "+
              "to edit in a single line of code.</p>";
```

There are also several ways to solve the "html syntax highlighting". I tend to use a simple trick of setting the html snippets in `<script>` tags or in hidden (`display:none`) `<div>` tags.

```
<div id="snippet" style="display:none">
  <h1>A Long html snippet</h1> 
  <p>This is a long html snippet that I don't want to be forced
  to edit in a single line of code.</p>
  <p>And I like some syntax highlighting, too</p>
</div>
```

and then use them in my code

```
var snippet = document.getElementById("snippet").innerHTML;
```

Finally, for a complete control, there are several preprocessor techniques and tools to preprocess html and js files. I use a template engine, jade is probably the best know, although I prefer EJS.

A good compendium of the second and third technique is the article John Resig I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I like your suggestions, I'm going to hold out for a preprocessor solution because I believe this way would have a lot of advantages, if it exists (amended the question)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MRJKb/1/

Convert html to json:

```
JSON.stringify(your_html_element.outerHTML)
```

Convert back to html:

```
JSON.parse(your_json_string);
```

---

The full fiddle:

```
<p>Original string:</p>

<div id="template">
    <div>
        My HTML here including whitespace...
    </div>
</div>

<p>JSON representation:</p>
<textarea rows="2" cols="60"></textarea>

<p>Back to html:</p>

<div id="output"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('textarea').val(
    JSON.stringify($('#template').html())
)
$('#output').html(JSON.parse($('textarea').val()))
```